# Drupal Inspect Element Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, amazon-web-services, drupal-7, firebug, developer-tools

I have a Drupal7 website hosted on an Amazon server and I am trying to mess with the front end.
I have a Bootstrap theme on it and most of the times when I try to see the css file paths with Firebug or Chrome developers tool or Firefox, instead of seeing the actual path I see a list of all the css files like this.

https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/v/1380796_10151958919174446_1486932695_n.jpg?oh=174373720a75f68dbfbacbcc06402a0d&oe=526FC558

Do you have any ideas why is this happening??!

Answer (score 1):

the link with the image is not working unfortunately so I cannot tell what is wrong there. Are you using the bootstrap theme or a subtheme? Is there also a Desktop view?

As Drupal Aggregates JS and CSS, was it regarding this? You can switch off Aggregation via: admin/config/development/performance Aggregate CSS & JS.

Answer (score 0):

The option to aggregate CCS & JS was already disabled. It came out that this behavior was caused by the Bitnami Drupal Stack. Migrating the project to a new server with a native Drupal installation fixed the problem.